# Why is my Schefflera losing healthy looking leaves?

Tags: leaves

I bought two scheffleras from a grocery store a few days ago. I've never had this type of plant before, so I'm unsure of what is normal for it or not. One seems to be doing better than the other. The one in question might be due for a repotting since I can notice some roots poking through the bottom. I plan to do that asap.  What I'm concerned about is if I'm providing enough light and water so far. There are a lot of healthy looking leaves that are falling off. Temperature in the house is set at 80 F. There are some yellowing on the edges of certain leaves and black spotting in others. What could be the cause of this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Could be a few things:

- spots on the leaves indicate a fungal/bacterial infection.  Healthy plants can resist this but plants in transplant shock, over watered or poorly rooted can be subject to attack.
- pull the plant out of the pot and check for the condition of the roots.  This plant is unlikely to be pot bound but it could have very few roots if it was rushed through the growing on cycle.  Healthy roots are firm and white. Older roots are a yellow ish colour and rotting roots are brown and soft.
- another possibility is cold air.  If you live where it is winter and the plant was not adequately wrapped when moved that would show the damage to the new growth that we see